# How do I shorten the java code for my loop

Tags: java, eclipse

beginner here.  I want to be able to ask the user a question.  If the user's answer is empty or contains only spaces, it should print out an error, then go back to the unanswered question.  Thus creating a loop until the question is answered. Please see code below:

```
    do {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Dog's name: ");
            String dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

            if(dogName.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: This can't be empty.");
                continue;   
            }
    do {
        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Breed: ");
            String breed = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();

            if(breed.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Breed can't be empty.");
                continue;   
            }
```

This code works but it gets very repetitive and long.  Is there a shorter and faster way of writing this? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you could factorize the common code with a method, that would take as parameters the question to ask to the user and what to display in case of an error, and which asks the user for input until the input is right, then return it. Afterwards, it's just a matter of calling that method once for name and once for breed.

Answer (score 5):

This is an ideal use case for a function. A function encapsulates a piece of code that you need multiple times and allows for both input via *parameters* and output via *return types*.

I suggest to read beginner tutorials of Java on how to use functions (also called *methods* in Java if they belong to a certain object, i.e. are not *static*).

Functions (also called procedures sometimes in other languages) are the basic building block of *procedural programming*, so I suggest you to learn about that topic as well.
In your specific case, that function could look like this:

```
String input(String label)
{
 System.out.print(label+": ");
 String s = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim(); // assuming "scan" is defined in the enclosing class
 if(s.isEmpty())
 {
  System.out.println("Error: "+label+" can't be empty.");
  return input(label);
 }
 return s;
}
```

This is a *recursive* function but you can do it iteratively as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method for the code which takes the question as a parameter,if the input is wrong you need to ask the same question, call the same method(recursion) with the same question.

pseudo code::

```
 public void test(String s) {
       System.out.print(s + ": ");
       String input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
       if(dogName.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println("Error: This can't be empty.");
          test(s);   
       } else {
         return input;
       }
```

To read about [recursion](https://www.javatpoint.com/recursion-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this so you can have many questions but same amount code, this is to illustrate the idea, may not fully work

```
    String questions[] = {"Dog's name: ","Breed: "};
    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(questions[i]);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = null;
        while(!(answer = scan.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("You answered: " + answer + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :

```
while ((dogName = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Error: This can't be empty.");
}
// Use dogName not empty

while ((breed = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Error: Breed can't be empty.");
}
// Use breed not empty
```

Best